# Propogation of _metadata from DataFrame to Series

Tags: python, pandas, metadata, dataframe, propagation

I want to be able to store 'units' information for each column of a DataFrame and have the following code (uisng pandas v 0.14.1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import copy

# Monkey path Series:
pd.Series._metadata.append('units')

# Test it
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(5,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
df['A'].units = 's'
df['B'].units = 'm'

s = df['A']
print s.units # produces 's' as expected / desired

s = copy.copy(df['A'])
print s.units # crash, attribute does not exists
print s._metadata # produces ['name', 'units'] as expected
```

Apparently the metadata is not propagated properly.
Is this a intentional or is this a bug?
If intentional what could be done to make this work?

Comment: using s.copy() will allow this. 2 work; it may be a bug that __ copy__ is not propagating (which is what copy.copy calls)

Answer (score 1):

`copy.copy(...)` currently works on pandas objects, but the mechanism doesn't preserve the metadata.

Here's an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8571) to implement this.

An easy workaround is simply to use `s.copy()` which will preserve the metadata.

Here is an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8572) to more fully document how to do this.